# How to change semantic-ui form validation prompt text dynamically (after validation)?

Tags: jquery, semantic-ui

I've the following (basic) semantic-ui form checking set up:

```
$('#form_login').form({
  fields: {
    username: {
      identifier: 'username',
      rules: [{
        type: 'empty',
        prompt: 'Please enter your user name'
      }]
    },
    password: {
      identifier: 'password',
      rules: [{
        type: 'empty',
        prompt: 'Please enter your password'
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

Works as advertised, but **I want for `prompt` text to be localized dynamically** -- when accessed.

How can I do that (since it doesn't accept function reference)?

Answer (score 1):

I think the prompt text can only be set statically in the current versions (2.1). I was trying to do something similar and I found the best way was to break up the rules so that each dynamic outcome was handled by custom rules.

For instance I made a form which the user, among other things, can update their password. I wanted the form to be submittable if no input was entered into the 'currentPassword' field, and otherwise adhere to usual password rules (new password can't be the same as the old one, min length of 6). In my form fields i set up the rules like so:

```
currentPassword: {
        identifier: 'currentPassword',
        optional: true,
        rules: [{
          type: 'empty',
          prompt: 'Please enter your current password'
        }]
      },
      newPassword: {
        identifier: 'newPassword',
        rules:[{
          type: 'newPasswordMinLength',
          prompt: 'Password must be at least 6 characters long!'
        },{
          type: 'newPasswordDifferent',
          prompt: 'New password must be different from your current one'
        }]
      },
      repeatPassword: {
        identifier: 'repeatPassword',
        rules: [{
          type: 'repeatPasswordMatch',
          prompt: 'Password does not match'
        }]
```

then I defined these custom rules:

```
  var currentPassElement = $('[name="currentPassword"]');
  var newPassElement = $('[name="newPassword"]');

  $.fn.form.settings.rules.newPasswordMinLength = function(value) {
    var currentPassValue = currentPassElement.length > 0 ? currentPassElement.val() : undefined;
    if(currentPassValue === undefined || currentPassValue.length === 0) {
      return true;
    }
    return value.length >= 6;
  };

  $.fn.form.settings.rules.newPasswordDifferent = function(value) {
    var currentPassValue = currentPassElement.length > 0 ? currentPassElement.val() : undefined;
    if(currentPassValue === undefined || currentPassValue.length === 0) {
      return true;
    }
    return value.toString() !== currentPassValue.toString();
  };

  $.fn.form.settings.rules.repeatPasswordMatch = function(value) {
    var currentPassValue = currentPassElement.length > 0 ? currentPassElement.val() : undefined,
        newPassValue = newPassElement.length > 0 ? newPassElement.val() : undefined;
    if(currentPassValue === undefined || currentPassValue.length === 0) {
      return true;
    }
    return value.toString() === newPassValue.toString();
  };
```

[Here is the semantic ui source file](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/blob/2.1.8/src/definitions/behaviors/form.js) where they define the default rules/prompts/etc. Its a good reference, and also shows how you can display values and such within the prompt.